# Adverbial clause's subject

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **While quite strong**, some people can resist this medicine's
> effect.

In this sentence, the subject of While quite strong is some people?

Is that means While people are quite strong, they can resist this medicines's effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *logical* subject of the "while quite strong" is "this medicine". However, the sentence is not well-structured, and I am sure some authorities would advise against it. The problem is with the logic of the sentence---there is nothing in the second clause that can be filled into the *while* clause to complete it grammatically:

- While some people quite strong, ... [wrong]
- While this medicine quite strong, ... [wrong]
- While this medicine's effect quite strong, ... [wrong]

A slightly better sentence would be:

- While it's quite strong, some people can resist this medicine's effect

Not only is this sentence grammatical, there is also no danger that the *it* would be taken to refer to *some people*, because in that case we would use *they*.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sentence can be rather explained in this way:

> ***Although this medicine's effect is quite strong***, some people can resist it.

[While](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv69.shtml) used to expressed contrast (meaning "whereas"), would need to combine a disadvantage with an advantage. Two advantages cannot be connected with ***while*** to show contrast - in this case "while" could simply indicate simultaneity.

> While she was good at maths, she was also excelling in literature.

Here "while" might enhance the difference of skills needed in maths as opposed to literature.